# C program not running in VSCode Macbook M1

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, apple-m1, vscode-debugger

I have installed MinGw via Homebrew on my M1 Macbook. I wanted it to be used for C programming on VSCode. I have installed the C/C++ extension by Microsoft and Code Runner extension. The output runs on the debug console. This is my sample code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("hi\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The settings for compiler show CLang,GCC build and lldb. On trying to choose any other option,a json file opens up.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        },
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file"
        },
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

On clicking debug C/C++ file,it asks for folder access permission and then loads symobls in the debug console,however it cannot take input as it shows an error

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=thread-selected,id="1"
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/kartikeydoshi/Desktop/untitled folder/test4",target-name="/Users/kartikeydoshi/Desktop/untitled folder/test4",host-name="/Users/kartikeydoshi/Desktop/untitled folder/test4"
Loaded '/usr/lib/dyld'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/Users/kartikeydoshi/Desktop/untitled folder/test4'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_collections.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_product_info_filter.dylib'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/liboah.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
hi
3
Unable to perform this action because the process is running.
```

The terminal shows the following

```
*  Executing task: C/C++: gcc build active file 

Starting build... /usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "/Users/kartikeydoshi/Desktop/untitled folder/test4.c" -o "/Users/kartikeydoshi/Desktop/untitled folder/test4"

Build finished successfully.  *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I have selected Run in Terminal in VSCode settings. It seems that the code runs in debug console and not in terminal(which it should).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Using MinGW on a Mac is really, really strange. It's basically a way to give Windows the tools that macOS and Linux have by default. Why not just use the native tools?

Comment: Just install the "XCode Command-Line Tools" and you'll have a full compiler set ready to go, and as a bonus, it's all ARM out of the box.

Comment: @tadman i already have installed command line tools. I cannot seem to select Clang as my compiler as it shows the aforementioned json file when selected.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact procedure to link it up with the XCode `clang` tools, but it's got to be a more standard way than the MinGW approach. [Did this work?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac). It's also worth mentioning that XCode itself is a very capable IDE as well, which if you're working on non-trivial projects might be a better experience.

Comment: W in MinGW stands for "Windows". If you are not planning to run your program on Windows, you don't need MinGW.